# one to many relationship and includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My problem is: each entry in view calls new sql query altough i used includes in controller. These sql queries are not efficient. Any help will be appreciated.

Entry model

```
has_many :training_entries
```

TrainingEntry model

```
belongs_to :entry
```

entries controller

```
@entries = Entry.includes(:training_entries)
```

view

```
<% @entries.each do |entry| %>

  <% if entry.training_entries.where("category_id =?",1).exists? %> 
   ok 
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<% @entries.each do |entry| %>

  <% if entry.training_entries.detect { |t_entr| t_entr.category_id == 1 } %> 
   ok 
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

change detect with select if you need to filter more than one element.

Comment: Thank u sir. I have never heard of detect.

Comment: It's a method of enumerable: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html